# Issuing email addresses to users

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp

What needs to be done for an application to be able to issue email addresses, such as `user123@mydomain.com`?

I'm using Amazon SES to send out emails, do they have a service for this or would this have to do with the domain registrar (GoDaddy), or both?

The client to check email would be the web application itself.

I'm using C#.Net and Mvc for that as far as development is concerned but would prefer to use existing SaaS wherever possible.

What are some good ways to go?

**EDIT:** I checked with GoDaddy and they can't do this at scale. I don't believe Amazon does this either. How is this done?

Comment: Amazon SES is outgoing service and not for incoming emails, so you would need postfix or exchange in order to be able to create mailboxes I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a [mail server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mail_servers). As you can see from the list there are plenty of mail servers that exist, however there are some serious leaders in the field:

> According to one survey, sendmail, Microsoft Exchange Server, Postfix,
>   and Exim together control over 85% of market share for SMTP service in
>   2010.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mail_servers)

I strongly recommend *not* hosting such a server in your code (if an implementation even exists, which I couldn't find)

After configuration of the mail server (which may need some intensive investment either in time or money, since this is complicated; some mail servers are notoriously complicated) you point your domain to the mail server. Mails can now be received to the email adresses you define.

This process is complicated, and I have a feeling that your question shows you don't know exactly what you need either (In fact I would have recommended closing it as too broad). I'd recommend reformulating exactly what you need and what you have so far. Don't hesitate to get in touch with someone that may help you formulate your needs.

Comment: thanks, what I meant about "in my code" part was one that has a C# API, not hosting. but thanks for the market share part, as far as administration, seems like a good way to go is Microsoft Exchange Server Online  hosted service, if the business can afford it.. it runs $4 per user per month.

Answer (score 1):

This would all depend on your implementation of email server host. If you are running Windows with IIS and Email Post office then users are of the host domain. You can use the admin scripts for adding users from the site in this case.

If you are using **Linux** and a thrid party email service, it will likely have a user interface for adding users. Howerver these implementations generally use MySQL on the backend so you can add users through script from an implementation of PHP through Apache webserver host or backend service that adds users through MySQL script.

Comment: Thanks, I'm running Windows/IIS.. what is "Email Post office"? My solution is .NET/C# based like I mentioned, so I'm looking for those solutions first

Comment: In Windows Server 2008 R2 there is a role that will add a Post Office or POP service to the server. This will allow users to retrieve email using any POP capable email software. Using .NET you can add users to you server or domain.